# Kinnos on Yom Ho'atzmo'us

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, song-poetry, zionism, yom-haatzmaut

Does anyone know of a siddur that has in it the Edah HaChareidi kinnos on Yom Ho'atzmo'us?
(I do not actually support the recital of this, however I am interested to see such a siddur and what the kinnos actually contain)

Comment: I don't think that ordinary chareidim say kinnot on Yom Ha'atzmaut. I once ended up at a chareidi minyan then and they just didn't seem to mark it in any way. Satmar probably does though.

Comment: @Scimonster, could they have been Chardalim? I have heard that in the Mir, the custom is to have a regular davening, even though many students there are zionist. I know that Satmar and Neturei Karta both say kinnot.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - for chareidim it's a non-issue. Ignored.

Comment: Editing in why you think that the Edah HaChareidi [sic] recites kinnot would strengthen this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58017/discussion-on-question-by-joshua-pearl-kinnos-on-yom-hoatzmous).

Answer (score -1):

You will not find any shul that says kinnos on Yom Ha'atzmaut.  This misconception may have stemmed from the fact that during some years Yom Haatzmaut falls out on Behab(The Monday Thursday, and Monday fasts, that some people are accustomed to fast and say Selichos in Iyaar). Some shuls may say selichos on Yom Haatzmaut for this reason but never kinnos.

Comment: Note this doesn't happen anymore, since Yom Ha'atzmaut can no longer fall on Monday, but is pushed off to Tuesday (as in this year 5777).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ananymous!

Comment: While it is difficult to prove the negative, editing in your sources of information always improves an answer.